# How to display returned json using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

[image]

I have the following jquery code:

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Ajax/getTableRecord",
                        data:{ i : id, t: 'mylist'},                        
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        }
```

When I activate this, the php function getTableRecord, queries a db and ends with:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

I can see the correct returned data in my console. However the alert function just shows the contents of the screenshot. How do I display the returned key value pairs in the alert box instead?

Comment: why don't you use ```console.log``` and view in the console ?

Comment: use console.log to print your data into the developer tools console

Comment: dataType: text , or JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: alert(data.array_key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
console.log(data);
```

or [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) like this

```
JSON.stringify(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the console

```
console.log(data);
```

instead of

```
alert(data);
```

you can check how to open the console on each browser here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers